# Asp.net MVC C# - DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list which is being populated with data from a database using a datasource in visual studio 2010. All the values are unique and I have set up an event to carry out an action when a new value is selected. When I select a new value in the drop down list the new value is selected but the event does not fire. I put a break point in the code to see if it was being executed which was not being hit.

I read about setting the drop down lists AutoPostBack to true but all this seems to do is refresh the page and set the list back to its original selected state (possible why the event is not firing?).

I also read something about enabling the ViewState as this could cause it to not fire, I tried putting EnableViewState = "true" at the top of the View to no avail. The EnableViewState property is also set to true on the drop down list.

I would be grateful if anyone has any insight into a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is this MVC or WebForms? Your Question title and then question content are confusing. MVC does not have `ViewState`, `AutoPostBack` or `EnableVeiwState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Asp.Net MVC you do not have events and postback like Asp.Net.

You should use a `form` tag to handle the values of your drop down, because it's a classic HTML page. If you want to handle in a async way, use javascript connected to the `onchange` of your dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I usually find this is caused by databinding. If code in Page_Load binds the dropdownlist without checking Page.IsPostBack (Or somewhere else in the pipeline before control events are handled) that will suppress the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Another possibility is that you haven't got OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListId_SelectedIndexChanged" in the decalrative markup for the control, or in the @Page directive you don't have AutoEventWireup=true.

Can you post your code?

Just seen tag and @iridio's post. Is this really MVC ? I would'nt expect to see System.Web.UI.WebControls used in an MVC app, but I am no MVC expert.